# c++ Directx11 capture screen and save to file

Tags: c++, save, screenshot, directx-11, texture2d

i've got problem with saving texture2d to file, it always gives me black image.
Here is code:

```
HRESULT hr = SwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), reinterpret_cast< void** >( &g_pSurface ) );
if( g_pSurface )
{
    ID3D11Texture2D* pNewTexture = NULL;

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC description;
    g_pSurface->GetDesc( &description );
    description.BindFlags = 0;
    description.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;

    HRESULT hr = d3d11Device->CreateTexture2D( &description, NULL, &pNewTexture );
    if( pNewTexture )
    {
        d3d11DevCon->CopyResource( pNewTexture, g_pSurface );

        hr=D3DX11SaveTextureToFileA(d3d11DevCon, pNewTexture, D3DX11_IFF_BMP, "screen.bmp");
        return;
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to be explicitly checking the return code for all functions that returned HRESULTs

```
HRESULT hr = SwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ),
    reinterpret_cast< void** >( &g_pSurface ) );
if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
...
    HRESULT hr = d3d11Device->CreateTexture2D( &description, NULL, &pNewTexture );
    if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
```

One possible point of failure is `CopyResource` which returns void so you can't detect the problem in your code. Instead you need to enable the Direct3D [DEBUG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) device and look for any ERROR or WARNING messages.

In particular, if your swap chain buffer is a MSAA resource this will fail to get any data. You have to explicitly use `ResolveSubresource` before doing the copy. In turn since `ResolveSubresource` returns a void, you need to check the format supports `D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_MULTISAMPLE_RESOLVE` before using it. Here's the code in the [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ScreenGrab) module in [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) that does this handling:

```
static HRESULT CaptureTexture( _In_ ID3D11DeviceContext* pContext,
                               _In_ ID3D11Resource* pSource,
                               _Inout_ D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC& desc,
                               _Inout_ ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>& pStaging )
{
    if ( !pContext || !pSource )
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    D3D11_RESOURCE_DIMENSION resType = D3D11_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_UNKNOWN;
    pSource->GetType( &resType );

    if ( resType != D3D11_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D )
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED );

    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> pTexture;
    HRESULT hr = pSource->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>( pTexture.GetAddressOf() ) );
    if ( FAILED(hr) )
        return hr;

    assert( pTexture );

    pTexture->GetDesc( &desc );

    ComPtr<ID3D11Device> d3dDevice;
    pContext->GetDevice( d3dDevice.GetAddressOf() );

    if ( desc.SampleDesc.Count > 1 )
    {
        // MSAA content must be resolved before being copied to a staging texture
        desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

        ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> pTemp;
        hr = d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, 0, pTemp.GetAddressOf() );
        if ( FAILED(hr) )
            return hr;

        assert( pTemp );

        DXGI_FORMAT fmt = EnsureNotTypeless( desc.Format );

        UINT support = 0;
        hr = d3dDevice->CheckFormatSupport( fmt, &support );
        if ( FAILED(hr) )
            return hr;

        if ( !(support & D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_MULTISAMPLE_RESOLVE) )
            return E_FAIL;

        for( UINT item = 0; item < desc.ArraySize; ++item )
        {
            for( UINT level = 0; level < desc.MipLevels; ++level )
            {
                UINT index = D3D11CalcSubresource( level, item, desc.MipLevels );
                pContext->ResolveSubresource( pTemp.Get(), index, pSource, index, fmt );
            }
        }

        desc.BindFlags = 0;
        desc.MiscFlags &= D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE;
        desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
        desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;

        hr = d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, 0, pStaging.GetAddressOf() );
        if ( FAILED(hr) )
            return hr;

        assert( pStaging );

        pContext->CopyResource( pStaging.Get(), pTemp.Get() );
    }
    else if ( (desc.Usage == D3D11_USAGE_STAGING) && (desc.CPUAccessFlags & D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ) )
    {
        // Handle case where the source is already a staging texture we can use directly
        pStaging = pTexture;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, create a staging texture from the non-MSAA source
        desc.BindFlags = 0;
        desc.MiscFlags &= D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE;
        desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
        desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;

        hr = d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, 0, pStaging.GetAddressOf() );
        if ( FAILED(hr) )
            return hr;

        assert( pStaging );

        pContext->CopyResource( pStaging.Get(), pSource );
    }
```

> In fact, you should be using *DirectX Tool Kit* instead of the legacy `D3DX11` library. All versions of D3DX are deprecated as is the legacy DirectX SDK itself (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)). There are a number of easily available [replacements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx).

In addition to the MSAA issue, you might be running into problems with `D3DX11`'s choice of WIC formats. Depending on your render target format and rendering, it might be writing out an image with an all 0 alpha channel which can result in a 'blank' output image. The *DirectX Tool Kit* ScreenGrab module gives you the ability to explicitly specify the output format and defaults to trying to use a non-alpha output file format for just this reason.

One more reason not to use legacy `D3DX11`: It was never updated for DXGI 1.1 formats so it won't support writing out BGRA format resources like `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` or `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` even when the underlying WIC container file format supports them. If your render target in your code above is `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` rather than `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` then `D3DX11` will fail while ScreenGrab will work fine.

Did I mention `D3DX11` is crazy old and hasn't had any fixes made to it since ~2009?

Here's some example usage for *ScreenGrab*:

```
ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBufferTex;
hr = swapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), ( LPVOID* )&backBufferTex);
if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
{
    // Write out the render target as a PNG
    hr = SaveWICTextureToFile( context.Get(), backBufferTex.Get(), GUID_ContainerFormatPng, L"SCREENSHOT.PNG");

    // Write out the render target as JPG
    hr = SaveWICTextureToFile( context.Get(), backBufferTex.Get(), GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, L"SCREENSHOT.JPG" );

    // Write out the render target as BMP
    hr = SaveWICTextureToFile( context.Get(), backBufferTex.Get(), GUID_ContainerFormatBmp, L"SCREENSHOT.BMP" );

    // Write out the render target as BMP and explicitly use a 16-bit format
    hr = SaveWICTextureToFile( context.Get(), backBufferTex.Get(), GUID_ContainerFormatBmp, L"SCREENSHOT.BMP", &GUID_WICPixelFormat16bppBGR565 );

    // Write out the render target as a TIF
    hr = SaveWICTextureToFile( context.Get(), backBufferTex.Get(), GUID_ContainerFormatTiff, L"SCREENSHOT.TIF" );

    // Write out the render target as a TIF with explicit WIC codec properties
    hr = SaveWICTextureToFile( context.Get(), backBufferTex.Get(), GUID_ContainerFormatTiff, L"SCREENSHOT.TIF", nullptr,
                                [&](IPropertyBag2* props)
                                {
                                    PROPBAG2 options[2] = { 0, 0 };
                                    options[0].pstrName = L"CompressionQuality";
                                    options[1].pstrName = L"TiffCompressionMethod";

                                    VARIANT varValues[2];
                                    varValues[0].vt = VT_R4;
                                    varValues[0].fltVal = 0.75f;

                                    varValues[1].vt = VT_UI1;
                                    varValues[1].bVal = WICTiffCompressionNone;

                                    (void)props->Write( 2, options, varValues ); 
                                });

    // Write out the render target as a DDS
    hr = SaveDDSTextureToFile( context.Get(), backBufferTex.Get(), L"SCREENSHOT.DDS" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your description is declared but not initialized to anything before setting all your values.  Its `MiscFlags` member could have garbage in it that's mucking up your creation. Try setting `description.MiscFlags = 0;` or zeroing out the entire description first.  If that doesn't do it, here's a stripped down code sample from one of my current libraries that works:

Try this:

```
HRESULT hr;

ID3D11Resource* pSurface = nullptr;
m_pRenderTargetView->GetResource(&pSurface);

if (pSurface)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(desc));
    desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.Width = clientWidth;
    desc.Height = clientHeight;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    desc.BindFlags = 0;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

    ID3D11Texture2D* pTexture = nullptr;
    hr = m_pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &pTexture);
    if (pTexture)
    {
        m_pContext->CopyResource(pTexture, pSurface);
        hr = D3DX11SaveTextureToFileA(m_pContext, pTexture, D3DX11_IFF_PNG, "ss.png");
        pTexture->Release();
    }
    pSurface->Release();
}
```

Comment: Your code will also fail if the surface is MSAA or if it is using a BGRA format. And it is using the legacy ``D3DX11`` library.

Comment: Yes, my answer most closely matches what it appears the OP was actually attempting to do/use without introducing much change to their code, but I agree with your sentiments and upvoted yours as the more sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

to write MSAA buffer (which is back-buffer in the swap chain) one needs use 'ResolveSubresource' instead of 'CopyResource'.

This is a simple code segment:

```
          D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
          HRESULT hr = S_OK;
          ID3D11Resource* pSurface = nullptr;

          // get pointer to back-texture from the swap chain referred from the pointer IDXGISwapChain* g_pswapChain
          hr=g_pswapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pSurface));
          if (FAILED(hr) || pSurface==nullptr)
          {
             // Throw Error  
      
          }
        
          D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
          ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(desc));
          desc.ArraySize = 1;
          desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
          desc.Width = 640; // i specified hard-coded the window size 640x480 in CreateWindowA
           desc.Height = 480;
           desc.MipLevels = 1;
           desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
           desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
           desc.BindFlags = 0;
           desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;  // data directly will be copied from GPU to a file
          desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

          ID3D11Texture2D* pTexture = nullptr;

          // g_pdevice is pointer to device ID3D11Device
          hr = g_pdevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &pTexture);
          if (pTexture)
          {
                  // instead of CopyResource(pTexture, pSurface), g_pd3dContext pointer to context ID3D11DeviceContext
                  g_pd3dContext->ResolveSubresource(pTexture, 0, pSurface, 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM);

                  // save rendered image as bmp-file
                  hr = D3DX11SaveTextureToFileA(g_pd3dContext, pTexture, D3DX11_IFF_BMP, "test.bmp");
                  pTexture->Release();
              }
              pSurface->Release();
```