# Is Desktop/screenshot capture with screengrab from DirectX Tool Kit possible?

Tags: c++, performance, screenshot, fullscreen, directx-11

So, getting to the metal right away. I'm writing a c++ program which purpose is to take the screen as an input image and process it with an object detector (from dlib) but I'm having troubles understanding how one can get a pointer to a swapChain and context/content of the screen.

The following code from [ScreenGrab (DirectX Tool Kit)](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ScreenGrab) seems to be able to do the trick. The issue is that I don't know how to get it to work. I'm using NuGet in visual studio 2017 to get the library (called directxtk_uwp, there is also one called directxtk_desktop_2015 which I am not using.) and I'm getting the following six errors:

> - error C2065: 'swapChain': undeclared identifier
> - error C2227: left of '->GetBuffer' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
> - error C2065: 'immContext': undeclared identifier
> - error C2228: left of '.Get' must have class/struct/union
> - error C2653: 'DX': is not a class or namespace name
> - error C3861: 'ThrowIfFailed': identifier not found

from running the inserted example code from the ScreenGrab wiki-page:

```
#include <ScreenGrab.h>
#include <wrl\client.h>
#include <Wincodec.h>


int main() {


    using namespace DirectX;
    using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer;
    HRESULT hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D),
        reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(backBuffer.GetAddressOf()));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = SaveWICTextureToFile(immContext.Get(), backBuffer.Get(),
            GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, L"SCREENSHOT.JPG");
    }
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);


        return 0;
}
```

I have really just started out programming with c++ and came from Java programming, which I've been actively developing in for a year now. So keeping it simple to understand would be appreciated ^^

Just to be clear, I would like something rather fast. I have gotten a screengrab to work with GDI with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wincodec.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <atlimage.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    try
    {
        int nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        int nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
        HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
        HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
            clock_t begin = clock();
            HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC,
                nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
            SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);
            BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight,
                hDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
            CImage image;
            image.Attach(hCaptureBitmap);
            image.Save("test.jpg");
            DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
            cout << double(clock() - begin) / (clock_t)1000 << endl;
        }
        ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd, hDesktopDC);
        DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
        IDirect3DSurface9 *surface;
        system("pause");
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cout << "\nexception thrown!" << endl;
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

which results in the following:

```
0.091
0.05
0.052
0.06
0.047
0.05
0.057
0.06
0.06
0.051
```

and as you can see, that really only gets my up to 1/0.47 ≈ 21 frames per second. I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33112422/8270455) answer, but yet again, I have no clue how to get the context and swapChain of the screen.
Thank you.

Comment: The example code you are using avoid assumes you are trying to take a screenshot of your own render target texture (created directly or obtained from the your own swapchain). This works as intended for your own application, but taking a screenshot of the desktop as a whole is a different matter which requires using the DXGI APIs. You should take a look at [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen#Capture%20It%20the%20GDI%20way) for some options.

Comment: The sample code on the DirectX Tool Kit [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki) assumes you at least looked briefly at the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) where I cover [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).

Comment: Thanks, Chuck! I was able to find that page as you can probably see in the variable names, I just couldn't remember the site. Never got the DirectX way of doing it to work, but that was quite early on and I think I have a better understanding now to do it. However, isn't DirectX9 rather outdated like you said in the linked question about DirectX11? Anyhow, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ah, right. I should have looked more closely as I thought they were doing the DXGI solution. Here's a more recent [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/03/25/ways-to-capture-the-screen/), [article](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1116253/desktop-screen-capture-on-windows-via-windows-desk), and [codebase](https://github.com/pgurenko/DXGICaptureSample).

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much, Chuck! This should do it. It's nice to have an expert to point one in the right direction sometimes ^^

Answer (score 1):

So after a little more looking and with the guidance of the great Chuck! I've found a solution that is about 3.5 times as fast at saving screenshots to disk (if you remove drawing mouse and the overhead of having 8 milliseconds in the beginning of the grabImage function). You can see the code [here](https://gist.github.com/Arnold1/0bec046c0d82c6a78ea13ee7c4f176b3). The following is the resulting time in milliseconds of saving ten images to the disk:

```
0.015
0.017
0.012
0.021
0.012
0.019
0.012
0.022
0.018
0.015
```

Summing these up and the others from the GDI program, we get 0.578/0.163≈3.546 times the speed. Keep in mind that I have replaced this part:

```
// Copy image into GDI drawing texture
        lImmediateContext->CopyResource(lGDIImage, lAcquiredDesktopImage);

        // Draw cursor image into GDI drawing texture
        CComPtrCustom<IDXGISurface1> lIDXGISurface1;

        hr = lGDIImage->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&lIDXGISurface1));

        if (FAILED(hr))
            return false;

        CURSORINFO lCursorInfo = { 0 };

        lCursorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lCursorInfo);

        auto lBoolres = GetCursorInfo(&lCursorInfo);

        if (lBoolres == TRUE)
        {
            if (lCursorInfo.flags == CURSOR_SHOWING)
            {
                auto lCursorPosition = lCursorInfo.ptScreenPos;

                auto lCursorSize = lCursorInfo.cbSize;

                HDC  lHDC;

                lIDXGISurface1->GetDC(FALSE, &lHDC);

                DrawIconEx(
                    lHDC,
                    lCursorPosition.x,
                    lCursorPosition.y,
                    lCursorInfo.hCursor,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    DI_NORMAL | DI_DEFAULTSIZE);

                lIDXGISurface1->ReleaseDC(nullptr);
            }

        }

        // Copy image into CPU access texture
        lImmediateContext->CopyResource(lDestImage, lGDIImage);
```

with the following line:

lImmediateContext->CopyResource(lDestImage, lAcquiredDesktopImage);

since I did not need the cursor. In fact, it might be worse to have it considering I'll be detecting things on the screen. As mentioned before, I have also relocated the line `Sleep(8); // not sure if required` from here:

```
    hr = lDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, NULL, &lDestImage);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    if (lDestImage == nullptr)
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool grabImage() {
    int lTryCount = 4;

    do
    {
        Sleep(8); // not sure if required
```

to here, in the init function:

```
    hr = lDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, NULL, &lDestImage);

    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    if (lDestImage == nullptr)
        return false;
    Sleep(8);
    return true;
}

bool grabImage() {
    int lTryCount = 4;

    do
    {
            //Sleep(5); // not sure if required
```

You could remove it completely as well, although that seems to cause "blank"/black image files in the beginning. For me, there were only two blank images before it began to capture. With the delay after the whole init function, I'm getting the first images as well without the overhead. Thank you.